# Изменить строки в файле

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как с помощью регулярных выражений изменить разрешение в файле на разрешение экрана компьютера?

```
"video.cfg"
{
    "Version"       "0"
    "VendorID"      "4318"
    "DeviceID"      "7944"
    "setting.cpu_level"     "2"
    "setting.mem_level"     "2"
    "setting.gpu_mem_level"     "2"
    "setting.defaultres"        "1920"
    "setting.defaultresheight"      "1080"
    "setting.gpu_level"     "3"
    "setting.version"       "1"
    "setting.knowndevice"       "0"
    "setting.refreshrate_numerator"     "0"
    "setting.refreshrate_denominator"       "0"
    "setting.fullscreen"        "0"
    "setting.coop_fullscreen"       "0"
    "setting.nowindowborder"        "1"
    "setting.mat_vsync"     "0"
    "setting.fullscreen_min_on_focus_loss"      "1"
    "setting.high_dpi"      "0"
    "setting.cl_particle_fallback_base"     "0"
    "setting.cl_particle_fallback_multiplier"       "0"
    "setting.dota_cheap_water"      "0"
    "setting.r_deferred_simple_light"       "1"
    "setting.r_ssao"        "1"
    "setting.cl_globallight_shadow_mode"        "2"
    "setting.r_dota_fxaa"       "1"
    "setting.r_deferred_additive_pass"      "1"
    "setting.r_deferred_specular_bloom"     "1"
    "setting.r_deferred_specular"       "1"
    "setting.r_texture_stream_mip_bias"     "0"
    "setting.r_dota_normal_maps"        "1"
    "setting.r_dashboard_render_quality"        "1"
    "setting.shaderquality"     "1"
    "setting.recommendedheight"     "2160"
    "setting.r_grass_quality"       "2"
    "setting.r_dota_allow_wind_on_trees"        "1"
    "setting.r_depth_of_field"      "1"
    "setting.mat_viewportscale"     "1.000000"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно попробовтаь)

```py
import re
import screeninfo

# Получить разрешение экрана компьютера
screen = screeninfo.get_monitors()[0]
screen_width = str(screen.width)
screen_height = str(screen.height)

# Открыть файл и прочитать его содержимое
with open("video.cfg", "r") as file:
    file_content = file.read()

# Заменить значения разрешения в файле на значения разрешения экрана
file_content = re.sub(r'"setting.defaultres"\s+"(\d+)"', f'"setting.defaultres" "{screen_width}"', file_content)
file_content = re.sub(r'"setting.defaultresheight"\s+"(\d+)"', f'"setting.defaultresheight" "{screen_height}"', file_content)

# Записать измененное содержимое файла обратно в файл
with open("video.cfg", "w") as file:
    file.write(file_content)
```